# Changing of css on button click not working in blazor .net 8

Tags: c#, blazor

I am trying to minipulate a css class from blazor in the code behind but no matter what I do am not having much luck.

```
private async Task<int> SetAnswerColorAsync()
{
   cssClass = isCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect";

   if (isCorrect)
   {
      await js.InvokeVoidAsync("appendToElement", $"{OptionId}", cssClass, "Correct Message");
          
    }
    
    else
    {
        await js.InvokeVoidAsync("appendToElement", $"{OptionId}", cssClass, "In Correct");
    }
    return 1;
}
```

[image]

You will see here each choice is as option_Number

```
<div class="container"><div class="quiz"><!--!-->
<p id="feedbackMessage">Test</p><!--!--><div class="app-title">
                Quizzing!</div>
<div class="quiz-header">How much is 1+1?</div><!--!-->
 <div class="quiz-body"><!--!-->
<div class="option" id="option_0" b-te071097yv="">1</div>
<!--!--><div class="option" id="option_1" b-te071097yv="">999</div>
<!--!--><div class="option" id="option_2" b-te071097yv="">2</div>
<!--!--><div class="option" id="option_3" b-te071097yv="">Abrahan Lincoln</div></div><button>Submit Quiz</button></div></div>
```

When its the correct option I want it to change the option to a different color which is defined in the site css.

```
.option {
    background-color: #fff;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -0.3px 0.3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}


.incorrect 
{
    background-color: red;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -0.3px 0.3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
.correct {
    background-color: green;
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 8px;
    cursor: pointer;
    box-shadow: -0.3px 0.3px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
}
 
.option:hover {
    background-color: #28a745;
    color: #fff;
    border-radius: 3px;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

The function is being called by the onlick

```
protected async void SelectOption()
{
   var test = OptionId;
   GetOptionStyle(Option);
   SetAnswerColorAsync();
   await OnOptionSelected.InvokeAsync(Option);
}
```

The html

```
<div class="option" id="@OptionId" @onclick="SelectOption">@Option</div>
```

Comment: What is the `appendToElement` function? Why are you manipulating the DOM via JS rather than using Blazor? Also, you're not awaiting your call to `SetAnswerColorAsync`

Comment: @KurtHamilton I wasnt aware of a way to do it via pure blazor?

Comment: You can just put your isCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect" in the html via:
<div class="my-class @(@isCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect")"> </div>

Answer (score 1):

When manipulating the DOM - in your case altering the class list - you should use Blazor when possible. Any changes made via JS will probably be lost whenever Blazor decides to re-render the component.

Below is a trivial example of changing the class list based on some local state.

```
<style>
.red { background-color: red; }
.green { background-color: green; }
</style>

<div class="my-class @Color">
This is a target div
</div>

<button @onclick="@(() => SetColor("red"))">Red</button>
<button @onclick="@(() => SetColor("green"))">Green</button>
@code {
  private string Color { get; set; }

  private void SetColor(string color)
  {
    Color = color;
  }
}
```

Notice how I am setting the value of the `Color` property based on some event, and using the value in the `class` attribute. I have also included the arbitrary `my-class` to show that you can combine static and dynamic values.

Your use case is more complex, in which case you can use a function to deduce which class to add to an option.

```
<div class="my-class @GetClass()"></div>

@code {
  private string Color { get; set; }
  private string GetClass()
  {
    return Color;
  }
}
```

Live demo of my example and your question scenario: https://blazorfiddle.com/s/nk1nsze8.

Comment: Im  not wanting the click of each button to determine the color bascially only the incorrect answers should turn it red for example thats why I had the bollean logic But it needs to be when the user clicks

Comment: I know. I included a trivial example to demonstrate how you can dynamically set the class using Blazor. You will, of course, need to apply your own logic in your own app.

Comment: Also, I did create a working version of your code in my blazor fiddle link. You may still need to tweak the logic to get it working in the way you want, but it still demonstrates complex class binding on a dynamic set of options.

Answer (score -1):

Cant you just do this?

```html
<div class="my-class @(@isCorrect ? "correct" : "incorrect")">

</div>
```